# Netlogo barriers, walls, and drawn lines narrower than a patch

Tags: netlogo, path-finding, maze

I'm working on a model of an event in a specific building. I have the floorplan. There's one issue: the building is large enough that if I make the walls take up a whole patch, making them easy to factor into pathfinding, the model is too large to run. So I have them narrower, and am treating them as turtles.

**But people are still walking through walls. I want them to not walk through walls.**

There's an intersection model in the library that means I can tell when someone has *already* walked into a wall, but that doesn't help with pathfinding. I can also draw lines where the walls are. But I'm not sure how to or even if it's possible to have lines register as locations.

Additionally, if I just use the whole patch that a wall occupies, that means there are no actual viable paths.

So: **how can I make a turtle that is less than a tenth of a patch wide impermeable to other turtles using a pathfinding algorithm?**

Comment: I don't tend to do obstacles so I don't have a good answer for you. But one option is a workaround - increase the number of patches (and reduce their size) so that the wall is a full patch.

Comment: I'm concerned about the size of the program if I change the number of patches - it's already a fairly large program. How much is increasing the size likely to increase the processing power it takes?

Comment: if your patches don't do anything (eg no `ask patches`) then it won't change much at all. Many ABMs have lots of processing for the agents (turtles) but very little for the environment (patches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I tried ended up being the massively increased number of patches, which added granularity to the simulation, which was cool.

The **fix** ended up being taking my floorplan and turning it into a png of just the walls and then uploading that and making it so agents couldn't walk through patches that color.